# Change child process's parent

Tags: c#

i was searching how to do it for about 6 hours,but didn't find a way.

Is there any way i can change a process's parent process? some api maby ?

google didn't gave much, same for this site, so i opened new question.

What i'm trying to do is to lock a file for personal use, then delete it.
i create the file on program A and use it with program B, when B finish the use, i delete with A, the thing is that B creates a sub process, which don't have B as his parent, so when i use :

```
File.Open(_moviePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Inheritable);
```

I try to lock the file because i don't want other programs/users to be able to copy it but
it failes.

tnx.

Comment: What kind of attack are you trying to protect from? A user can switch off PC after process A finished. Connect the drive to another PC and read the content hassle-free. Is that a problem?

Comment: That wouldn't even help; once you lock a file, only that stream / handle can access it.  `This is not directly supported by Win32`

Comment: Well , it's suppose to be a movie file that must not be copied in any way, just to be watched by a personal player i made (program B )

Comment: You would want to search for DRM protection. This will involve some form of encryption (for example AES) and key management solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of locking the file this way, why not use Mutex?  It allows for cross process locking.  This will work fine if this is to remain on a single box.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwe34f1k(v=vs.110).aspx

And no you cannot reassign a parent process owner to a child process.

Here is an example, i will explain below:  http://www.dotnetperls.com/mutex

using System;
using System.Threading;

```
class Program
{
   static Mutex _m;

   static bool IsMutexExisting(string token)
   {  
    try  
    {
      // Try to open existing mutex.
      Mutex.OpenExisting(token);
    } 
    catch
    {
      return true;
     }
     // More than one instance.
   return false;
   }
```

So in your example program A will do it's thing and then wait..  how to get A to wait?

Have program A attempt to open an existing mutex (a mutex that only B will create), for example...  pcode:

```
 while( IsMutexExisting("B Token") == false )
 {
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);  //sleep for a 1/2 sec
 }
 //ok, B has created the mutex, let's wait for it to be released indicating it is complete.
Mutex m = Mutex.OpenExisting("B Token");
m.WaitOne();  // will block execution until B releases the Mutex

 // lock created, this means B signaled us

 // do the rest of A code here...
```

Program B:

```
 <does what it does>
 //Create Mutex to signal A
 Mutex m = null;
 try{
     m =new Mutex(true,"B Token");

 ...
 ...
 }
 finally{
    m.ReleaseMutex();
 }
```

Comment: I'm not very familier with Mutex, i do know the use of it, but never implemented any code with it, i'll look into that. by saying "This will work fine if this is to remain on a single box." , single box will be same computer?

Comment: yes, cross process locking works obviously if running on same computer.  I will give you a simple example on my answer so I can get points!! =)

Comment: Thanks alot!!! i hope i will manage to get it to work with what i need , as the new process that b creates is program C, in my case VLC player, this one works with his own dlls that i have no access to, so the mutex should be placed there, i'll try to play around with it and hopefully it will work, Great answer and example, thanks again !